# Killing every process except system's and my own

Tags: c, unix, ubuntu, process

I'm trying to make a virus to run on VMWare so I could have some fun with Ubuntu and
experiment with it. Now, I would be interested that my experimental virus (although it's hardly a virus, it's more of an actual program) would be able to kill/terminate every process but itself and the system processes.

I thought of 2 options:

Either I get all the non-system processes IDs and kill each, comparing to mine first, to avoid killing myself.

OR there's an actual command or a function built-in doing that in some, I did some research and I succeeded making my process 'shielded' from any terminating/killing signals, but I'm not sure how to search other processes IDs (non-system ones).

Any idea on how to perform this?

Comment: What's your definition of a 'system' process?

Comment: @William Pursell a process that was not activated by the user and is necessary for the system to continue its run. Meaning I don't want to kill a process that will harm the system itself and will cause the computer to crash.

Comment: You will need a better definition.  By the definition given, one could argue that the only 'system' process is init (pid 0).  One could also argue that every process is a 'system' process.

Answer (score 1):

Following command is to list every process on the system.

ps aux

Comment: I saw that one, but how do I get only those that are system processes, internal processes that are fully necessary for the OS to run.

Comment: @Jack In general, Unix and Linux don't really distinguish between system processes and other processes. There are distinctions between daemons, interactive processes, batch/scheduled jobs, and other things like that but there isn't really anything that says "this is a system process"...